# SQL SERVER Identity changes daily

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table which has an Identity column requestID. I have set autoincrement and seed values, both to 1.
The requestId increases as expected. But It shows one unexpected behavior.
eg
if today's last increment is 500, next day's identity starts at 1001.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a job that triggers this reset every day?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL 2012 identity columns internally use sequences with CACHE for generating the values. While this improves performance, it has a side effect: an unexpected shutdown causes gaps in the sequence. There's nothing that can be done to prevent this. The official Microsoft guidance is that the application should not rely on the identity value to be sequential. 'Unexpected' shutdown includes, a power loss, Windows restart, and stopping SQL Server instance using NET STOP.

Answer (score 0):

Why is this a problem? Most likely there are 500 attempts to insert something and they all fail. It is not a must (and not the intention of the autoinc-column) to store consecutive numbers. It's intention is to provide unique numbers where each new number is greater than the previous thus giving a sort order on the insert sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the [following command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) daily:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.MyTable", RESEED, 0);
```

I assume that you're trying to keep track of the number of Requests by day, but you could see counting problems if any inserts fail i.e. there might be gaps in your numbers.

IMO it would be better to just not reset the field each day and store the insertion time into a column for the new record. Then you can query by date and get a count.